# what is the minimum capital necessary for quantitative/automated/algorithm trading?

Tags: r, statistics, quantitative

I mean from my home for myself
I have a degree in statistics so I know time series, predictions, R ...
I would like to design statistical model for trading with R 
I don't ask for trading strategies, only capital required